# setting a color value in the jlabel[] in java

Tags: java, user-interface

While I was writing a code, I found out that you can't do setColor to the Label I assigned. It tells me to put the length and put a variableDeclaration. However, I do not know ho to do that.. How do you assign a font type or a color for "JLabel[] answerLabels;"?

```
    JLabel[] answerLabels;
    answerLabels = new JLabel[question.getAnswers().length]; 
    answerLabels.length[new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,16)];
```

Answer (score 2):

#### I recommend you to learn more about arrays.

Look mate, you have an array(think of it as a list) of `JLabel`. Not a single `JLabel`

`JLabel[] answerLabels;`

The two square brackets`[]` after `JLabel` represent that you are creating an array, not a single `JLabel`.

Therefore, when you call,

```
answerLabels = new JLabel[question.getAnswers().length]; 
answerLabels.length[new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,16)];
```

you are not referring to a `JLabel` but you are referring to an array. Since, array doesn't have any methods such as, `setForeground()` or `setFont()`, your program will run into an error.

So if you want to set the color or font of a particular `JLabel`, you have to refer to it.
To refer to that `JLabel`, you have to write code as follows :

```
answerLabels[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
```

Here, '**i**' represents the number of `JLabel` you want to access. Suppose, you want to access the third `JLabel`, then you have to write 2 in the place of 'i' in the above line.

**Why 2, why not 3?** Because arrays start at 0.

**Note** that, the `JLabel` you are trying to access should be initialized before setting it's color or font by something like,

```
answerLabels[i] = new JLabel();
```

Otherwise, your program will throw `NullPointerException`. So, **make sure to initialize the `JLabel`** you are accessing from the array before setting it's color or font.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your trying to do something like this:

```
    JLabel[] answerLabels = new JLabel[question.getAnswers().length];
    // This will loop through all of the JLabels and set the font and color
    for(int i=0; i<answerLabels.length; i++) {
        answerLabels[i] = new JLabel("Text from question/answer");
        answerLabels[i].setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,16));
        answerLabels[i].setForeground(Color.red);
    }
```

Comment: Note that that the array is empty in this example, and that the array will need to be filled before using the 'for loop' to update all the labels. For example `answerLabels[0] = new JLabel("example");` or `answerLabels[1] = yourLabelName;`

Comment: Edited.  Thanks for catching @sorifiend!